# Simple rewrites in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

This seems like a very simple question, but I've only found complicated answers. I've got a Zend Framework application that requires users to login. The `loginAction()` and `logoutAction()` are defined in `AuthController`. I want to allow users to login via http://www.example.com/login rather than http://www.example.com/auth/login.

I know there are numerous ways of doing this, the 3 I've considered are:

1. .htaccess rewrite
2. Creating a LoginController and redirecting the indexAction() to auth/login
3. Defining my own routes using Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite.

I'd rather keep it out of #1 if possible. #2 is easy enough to understand, although it seems like a hack. It also could clutter the code with a bunch of 5-line "Controller" classes. I think #3 is the way to go but I don't fully understand how to use it effectively. I have tried [Using Zend_Config with the RewriteRouter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.add-config) although I only defined the login route so every link became '/login' (I think I was missing a default route). I did this in my Bootstrap.php, I'm not sure if that was correct.

Is there a simple approach I'm missing? Am I using #3 incorrectly? Are there tutorials for this that I should read? (I've looked at the Zend documentation which is good but often I find myself asking, 'Where should this code go: in a controller, model, bootstrap, other?')

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for a defined purpose like you have a *"named"* route would be the simplest way to do it. While there are any number of ways to implement a named route the easiest is to put it in the *application.ini:*

```
    // /application/configs/application.ini
    resources.router.routes.login.route = /login
    resources.router.routes.login.defaults.module = default
    resources.router.routes.login.defaults.controller = auth
    resources.router.routes.login.defaults.action = login
```

putting it in your bootstrap is not wrong, it just doesn't seem as convienient to me.
Also doing it this way **should** (no guarantees) prevent any problems with the default routes.

When calling a route using the url() helper it is important to remember to use either the named route :

```
<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'routeName') ?>
```

or if you need to pass the normal 'controller' => , 'action' => :

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'), 'default') ?>
```

near as I can tell 'default' in this context indicates this would be a default route as defined in *Zend/Controller/Router/Route/Module.php*

Comment: Per your instructions I've added these lines to my application/configs/application.ini and navigating to /login works great! However, all the links on the page (which are generated in a layout template with `$this->url(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'))`) are now /login. This only happens on the login page though, the links (and routes) from the home page and all other controllers work fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: Figured this out, I should be using `$this->url(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'), 'default')`. If the second parameter is `null` (or omitted) then the current route is assumed.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case that you are interested in how to do it in your bootstrab in correct way.

If you have only one route to rewrite, just add function:

```
protected function _initRoute() {
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addRoute('login', //key of route !
        new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
            'login', //this is url(www.url.com/login) that you want to rewrite, you can set whatever you want
            array(
                'module' => 'default',
                'controller' => 'auth',
                'action' => 'login',
            )
    ));
}
```

Now, every www.your-url.com/**login** request will point to 
www.your-url.com/default/auth/login (module/controller/action)

Edit:

---

If you want to use your new url in view file, you have to use key for that route

in view.phtml

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'login'); ?>">
   [link]
 </a>
```

The first parameter is array(), and the second one is key which you define in bootstrap.
Than if you change URL to /new-login in bootstrap, all URLs will be changed in view files.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to work in the same way that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8966962/961455) does, with the same strange behavior on the /login page with all the links being to /login. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you ask how to set all links dynamic point to new url ??
if not, can you little explain your "strange" behavior ?

Comment: All the links on the page (which are generated in a layout template with $this->url(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'))) are now /login. This only happens on the login page, the links (and routes) from the home page and all other controllers work fine.

Comment: I edit my answer, but I don't know where is the problem in your code. It isn't in routing, because both of answer is correct.
try to set: "$router->addDefaultRoutes();" at the and of _initRoute() that is my blind shot...

Comment: Hey. Set "... , 'default', true ..." !!!    

$this->url(array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar'), 'default', true);     :D