# ZF wrong route rewrite

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, zend-route

I've got 2 links in my layout.phtml and a route in the bootstrap:

```
1. Link:
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'aktuelles', 'action' => 'index'), null, true );
// creates: http://localhost/aktuelles

2: Link
echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'projekte', 'action' => 'wohnen', 'projektId' => 26), 'projekte-galeria', false);
// creates: http://localhost/projekte/wohnen/26

Route:
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $front->getRouter();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(  'projekte/wohnen/:projektId', 
                                            array(  
                                                    'module' => 'web',
                                                    'controller' => 'projekte',
                                                    'action' => 'wohnen',
                                                    'projektId' => null)
                                            );                  
$router->addRoute(  'projekte-galeria', $route);
```

When I load the page everything is displayed correctly and the urls are all correct.

**Problem:** As soon as i click on the second link (http://localhost/projekte/wohnen/26), the first link is changing:

from: localhost/aktuelles

to : localhost/projekte/wohnen

Why is the link changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to force to use the default route: instead of `null` use `'default'` as the second parameter in the first url.

BTW - the part `'controller' => 'projekte', 'action' => 'wohnen'` in the second url is redundant, because you predefine these parameters in the route. The second link could by simplified like this:

```
echo $this->url(array('projektId' => 26), 'projekte-galeria', false);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But why do i have to set it with the 'default' parameter instead of null? I thought null defines the default route?

Comment: Well, see the apidoc for the Url View Helper: _The name of a Route to use. If null it will use the current Route_. So it doesn't set it to `default`, it instead says "use the route used for routing this action".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution as an alternative way to handle routes [Simple rewrites in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966643/simple-rewrites-in-zend/8966962#8966962)