# Zend Routes translate URL's

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

1) I have a controller "calendar" and have action "showDate" which gets date via url. So, url is something like "calendar/show-date/date/2012-07-22"

2) I have a link to display all entries, "calendar/"

So, I want to create routes so my links look like "kalendar/2012-07-22" and "kalendar/".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

According to this post:
http://www.z-f.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5138

The solution is to add '@locale' => $lang to the params.

```
$this->url(array('lang'=>'it','@locale'=>'it'))
```

It works very well for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into translating the URL with Zend_Translate and I came across this sites' plugin that attempts to auto-translate URL segments (module/controller/action).

http://blog.helmich.cz/305-howto-simple-multilingual-routes-in-zend-framework/

The nice thing is that it's a modified custom router class that can function similar to Zend_Router so it's relatively familiar off the bat.

```
$pages = new MyApp_Controller_Router_Route(
    ':locale/:@controller/:@action/*',
    array(
        'controller' =>; 'index',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'locale'     => 'cs'
            )
);

$router->addRoute('pages',$pages);
```

The thing you'll need is to have a language ID in your URL (called :locale in the above example) so your Zend_Translate can set the proper language.

```
www.example.com/en/calendar/2012-06-22/
www.example.com/fr/calendrier/2012-06-22/
www.example.com/de/kalender/2012-06-22/
www.example.com/it/calendario/2012-06-22/
```

I've only slightly played around with this concept but I recall that it had promise.  You'll have to get more familiar with Zend_Translate: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html

I hope that helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could re-route all calls of *calendar* to *kalendar*. There are two possibilites, either you do it with Zend (preferable) or you change your webserver configuration to rewrite calls to *calendar* with a HTTP 302 (ugly).

You should however consult the official [Zend Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/db_Controller_Router_Rewrite.html#%5CZend_Controller_Router_Rewrite), which is pretty good

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup custom routes, this is my way:

in folder application/configs/ create file named "routes.ini"

Put in file your route:

```
;index-homepage, parameter date isn't required
;"index" is key of your route
routes.index.route = "kalendar/:date" 
routes.index.defaults.controller = calendar
routes.index.defaults.action = show
routes.index.defaults.date =
```

So in your bootstrap.php define that config file:

```
protected function _initRoute() {
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $router->addDefaultRoutes();

    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/routes.ini');
    $router->addConfig($config, 'routes');
}
```

And that's it, you can call URL

www.website.com/kalendar

and

www.website.com/kalendar/2012-1-1

See answers in this question for details: 
[Simple rewrites in Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966643/simple-rewrites-in-zend-framework/8968926#8968926)

Comment: This is what you want in action dogadjaji.rs/kalendar-dogadjaja and dogadjaji.rs/kalendar-dogadjaja/10/2012  :)

Comment: this does not match www.website.com/kalendar, it opens my showDate action with start_date param set to empty string

Comment: try to setup show-date, instead of showDate... I update my Answer.  You need to ask in controller if($_GET['start_date']){ ... } ... ofcourse

Comment: routes.index-homepage.route = "kalendar/" 
routes.index-homepage.defaults.module = frontend
routes.index-homepage.defaults.controller = calendar
routes.index-homepage.defaults.action = index

routes.index.route = "kalendar/:start_date" 
routes.index.defaults.module = frontend
routes.index.defaults.controller = calendar
routes.index.defaults.action = show
routes.index.defaults.start_date = 
This is my routes.ini and it allways opens showAction in calendar controller, from both /kalendar and /kalendar/2012-07-01 .. For first link should open index action and for second showAction..

Comment: this also would disable any other /kalendar/:action route that I would like to add. I suppose there should be something like /kalendar/([0-9\-]+)/ to point to showAction and /kalendar/:action to point to someAction..

Comment: If you want to have two different action, for second route setup routes.index.route = "kalendar/start_date"  (without :), and you can setup regexp routes.index.defaults.start_date = "([0-9\-]+)", everything else looks OK in your comment below.