# How to make localized seo-friendly urls with Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, seo, zend-route

I researched a lot, and I know this topic was discussed in other questions. However I believe the answers are not satisfying.

Many sources mention the importance of speaking urls for seo. Also google refers to localized urls and how to annotate them in xml sitemaps http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.de/2012/05/multilingual-and-multinational-site.html. On recent researches keywords in urls are mentioned as 3rd (or 4th) most important factor.

Using Zend I want to build and route localized seo friendly urls.

First of all examples for these urls:

en: mydomain.com/en/cars or mydomain.com/cars or en.mydomain.com/cars
german: mydomain.com/de/auto or mydomain.de/auto or de.mydomain.com/auto

however since I use a .me domain I need the urls either as subdomains or like /en/car/. This means url chaining. Not a big deal. More interesting is how to handle the dynamic part of the url (cars --> auto)

I only want one codebase for all languages so the controller should be called cars in this example.

How do I realize localizes urls with zend, both url building and routing? e.g. $this->url("controler"=>"cars","lang"=>"de") results in /de/cars. How you gonna build a flexible router for this kind of urls? Are there any solutions for this?

Or would you use only english urls for convenience and neglect the seo disadvantages?

Comment: You need to override $this->url() view helper to set one more parameter "lang" ...

Comment: Thought so @tasmaniski. And than have a look up array for the language specific urls and build the urls through regex?

Comment: ... and take a look on custom routes in ZF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155002/zend-routes-translate-urls/11155800#11155800