# How to translate URL's in zend framework 1.11

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to translate

Dutch :

http://example.com/login => http://example.com/inloggen

German

http://example.com/login => http://example.com/anmelden

Answer (score 0):

Take look on this doc http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard.translated-segments

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following so question:

[Zend Routes translate URL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155002/zend-routes-translate-urls?rq=1)

Might be what you are looking for.